# Fullscreen not functioning in virtualbox image open in vmware

Tags: fullscreen, vmware, virtualbox

For a project I was given a virtualbox image to work on. I don't have virtualbox but opened it in VMware and it works great except that in full screen the vm stays small and in the middle. I tried changing the autosize to stretch but it turns out obviously distorted and hard to work with. How do i get the fullscreen to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the display resolution within the OS, though I thought it should have done that automatically

Answer (score 0):

You probably lack VMWare Tools. You can install it with `VM > Install VMware Tools`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @GabeSechan I may have written it as a question, but it's an answer. This is only natural to not being able to resize VMs without VMware tools installed.